# with-local-quit: do I need to set quit-flag to nil?

Tags: quitting

I have this code:

```el
(defun my-test ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((inhibit-quit t))
      (with-local-quit
        (goto-char (point-min))       
        (while (search-forward "foo" nil t)
          (let ((b (copy-marker (match-beginning 0)))
                (e (copy-marker (match-end 0))))
            (query-replace "foo" "bar" nil b e))))
      (setq quit-flag nil)

      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward "bar" nil t)
        (let ((b (copy-marker (match-beginning 0)))
              (e (copy-marker (match-end 0))))
          (query-replace "bar" "foo" nil b e))))))
```

My purpose is to have the option to quit, with `C-g`, the first loop without ending the function execution. The code works but it seems a little strange to me the need to setting `quit-flag` to `nil` after the `with-local-quit` macro.

I'm doing it in the right way?

The info on https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quitting.html are not clear to me (but I have my limits).